# Change AppVerName and DefaultGroupName based on user input

Tags: inno-setup

I want my installer to ask user how program should be named in "Add\Remove Programs". I want to add custom wizard pages for this. There are no problems with custom wizard pages, but I do not know how to change AppVerName after wizard has been shown.
I already tried:

```
[Setup]
AppVerName={code:GetUserAppName}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{code:GetUserAppName}
DefaultGroupName={code:GetUserAppName}

[Code]
var
  AppUserName: String;

function GetUserAppName(param: String): String;
begin
  Result := AppUserName;
end;
```

But function `GetUserAppName` is called too early, before I have any chance to ask user for program name. And this function is not called after wizard is displayed or before installing.

Are there any possibility to change `AppVerName` from code, for example in `NextButtonClick` event?

P.S. There is already similar question: [Changing AppID and AppName based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999456/changing-appid-and-appname-based-on-user-input), but accepted answer is totally wrong, because his author asked wrong question:

> I found answers to my own question and then realised maybe I was not
>   asking the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There's [`UninstallDisplayName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayname), which is resolved only during the actual installation, when you already know the name. So you can use your `GetUserAppName` here:

```
[Setup]
UninstallDisplayName={code:GetUserAppName}
```

---

See also [Inno Setup Change AppName based on component(s) selected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35861235/850848).